# How to vectorize a python code that needs interpolation for specific data points

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have a problem where I use a computer program called MCNP to calculate the energy deposition in a square geometry from a particle flux.  The square geometry is broken down into a mesh grid with 50 cubic meshes in length, width and height.  The data is placed into a text file displaying the centroid position of each mesh in cartesian coordinates (x,y and z position) and the energy deposition at that x,y,z coordinate. The data is then extracted with a Python script.  I have a script that allows me to take a slice in the z plane and plot a heat map of energy deposition on that plane and the script works, but I dont think it is very efficient and I am looking for solutions to vectorize the process.

The code reads in the X, Y and Z coordinates as three separate 1-D numpy arrays and also reads in the energy deposition at that coordinate as a 1-D numpy array.  For the sake of this description, lets assume I want to take a slice at the Z coordinate of zero, but none of the mesh centroids are at the z-coordinate of 0, then I have to (and do) cycle through all of the data points in the Z-coordinate array until it finds one that is greater than zero (array index i) with a proceeding array index (i-1) that is less than zero.  It then needs to use those array points in Z-space along with the slice location (in this case 0) and the energy deposition at those array indices and interpolate to find the correct energy deposition at that z-location of the slice.  Since the X and Y arrays are unaffected, now I have the coordinate of X, Y and can plot a heat map of that specific X,Y location and the Energy deposition at the slice location.  The code also needs to determine if the slice location is already in the data set, in which case no interpolation is needed.  The code I have works, but I could not see how to use built in scipy interpolation schemes and instead wrote a function to do the interpolation.  In this scenario and had to use a for loop to iterate until I found the position where the z-position was above and below the slice location (z=0 in this instance).  I am attaching my example code in this post and am asking for help to better vectorize this code snippet (if it can be better vectorized) and hopefully learn something in the process.

```
# - This transforms the read in data from a list to a numpy array
#   where Magnitude represents the energy deposition
XArray = np.array(XArray); YArray = np.array(YArray)
ZArray = np.array(ZArray); Magnitude = np.array(Magnitude)

#==============================================================
# - This section creates planar data for a 2-D plot

# Interpolation function for determining 2-D slice of 3-D data
def Interpolate(X1,X2,Y1,Y2,X3):
    Slope = (Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)
    Y3 = (X3-X1)*Slope
    Y3 = Y3 + Y1
    return Y3

# This represents the location on the Z-axis where a slice is taken
Slice_Location = 0.0

XVal = []; YVal = []; ZVal = []
Tally = []; Error = []
counter = 1.0
length = len(XArray)-1
for numbers in range(length):
 #   - If data falls on the selected plane location then use existing data
    if ZArray[counter] == Slice_Location:       
        XVal.append(XArray[counter])
        YVal.append(YArray[counter])
        ZVal.append(ZArray[counter])
        Tally.append(float(Magnitude[counter]))

# - If existing data does not exist on selected plane then interpolate
    if ZArray[counter-1] < Slice_Location and ZArray[counter] > Slice_Location:
        XVal.append(XArray[counter])
        YVal.append(YArray[counter])
        ZVal.append(Slice_Location)
        Value = Interpolate(ZArray[counter-1],ZArray[counter],Magnitude[counter-1], \
                           Magnitude[counter],Slice_Location)
        Tally.append(float(Value))
    counter = counter + 1

XVal = np.array(XVal); YVal = np.array(YVal); ZVal = np.array(ZVal)
Tally = np.array(Tally);
```